# Can I prevent music through an AirPod from pausing when a single pod is removed?

Tags: ios, audio, watchos, airpods

Right now, when I remove one AirPod from an ear, the currently playing track pauses in the other ear.

Instead, I want to continue playing the track.

My control over this using bluetooth settings is quite limited, so I'm hoping there is another location to investigate to disable this feature.

Comment: The settings for lower volume and options are different than the removal detection. Let’s split this into two threads.

Answer (score 5):

Head into Settings > Bluetooth > AirPods > Turn Off Automatic Ear Detection feature

When the automatic ear detection feature is turned off, audio will continue to play even fi you take the AirPods out of your ears.